# Query UI Draggable Value Check

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I searched a couple places and I don't find anything regarding Query UI Draggable value...

For Example:

```
<p value="extreme">First Item</p>
<p>Second Item</p>
<p value="soft">Third Item</p>
```

Given the two items, I can drag them into a droppable. However I want to check if the item has a value on it, and I'm not sure how to do that.

I use .text to see if it has a text... but how do I look to see if it has value? It doesn't necessary need to be value, but something else that can differentiate between the items.

```
alert(ui.draggable.text());
```

Goal:
Given the above example, I pretty much just use the ui.draggable.text() to process any information. However, if it has a hidden value.. it'll do something else instead.

Comment: `ui.draggable.val()` ? `ui.draggable.attr('value')` ?

Comment: You are a genius! ui.draggable.attr('value') worked for me. Thank you... can't believe i forgot hah...

Comment: Banana, if you post that as an answer. I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome :) the trick is to remember that all jQuery methods return a jQuery object, just use the methods ur familiar with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

draggable is a jQuery object on which you can call the regular jQuery methods that you are familiar with. to get the value, you can simply use:

```
ui.draggable.val()
```

or

```
ui.draggable.attr('value')
```